# php or java comparing data

Tags: java, php, mysql, oracle

I am looking for a way to use php or java to compare the output of two sql queries. Normally I would use a dblink and write a sql query that would process a full outer join and check for data thats not identical.

However, Because the two databases do not have dblinks setup and I am not in a position where that will be the case, I write in php and I'm learning java so theoretically I could use that as well.

The front end of the application I'm writing is in php, a web interface handles the user login and database connection, it can gather the data as well. Then either another php application will need to review that data for identical records or it will have to pass it to a java application to do so.

Any help on how this might be done would be greatly appreciated.

Long and Short is this:

I have 2 multidimensional data structures in which unique keys are known but are typically more than 1 column. I need to identify any missing or different records. What are some ways this can be accomplished with php or java?

Cheers!

========================== update ============================

After looking at this for several hours, here is where I am at right now.

First I build a structure of data based on a query to databaseA. Then I build an identical data structure from that same query against databaseB.

After I have both of those collections, I dynamically create global temp tables based on that structure into one of my test environments. I then insert the collected data into those respective temp tables.
The last step will be to make a comparison of the data in those two temp tables and output that comparison somewhere - which shouldn't be difficult.

Where I'm stuck now is on INSERT into the temp tables.
It's painfully slow for > a few thousand records. I read this:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/seliverstov-multirows-098120.html

Now I'm working through trying to dynamically create a package that will handle the bulk inserts... Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know php at all and I only have a fuzzy idea about java. With that said:

If you were able to do everything in one database, a full outer join would be among the most inefficient ways to do it. Instead, the most efficient way is to do a UNION ALL, group by all the columns, and return only the groups with a group count of 1. That is: if a group has a count of 2, then the same row is present in both tables. (You mentioned a unique key which helps - the only duplicates in the UNION ALL will be of this kind, they will not be from the same table.)

For finer detail, when you UNION ALL you can add one more column to identify the source table - but the grouping is on the "base" columns (not including this flag).

Now: I don't know how you "bring in" the results from your two databases to php or java, but assume it's as some sort of text files, with one line per row in the output of your queries. Each language must have its text-manipulation facilities in which you can identify lines that are identical, do a count - mimicking what I described above. I know how to do that in Oracle SQL and also using UNIX tools; I don't know how to do that in php or java, but if you are conversant in these languages, perhaps you do.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the answer. I updated my question because at this point I think I've nailed down a conceptual solution. See above. Also - thanks for the tip about the union group I hadn't thought of that and I'll give it a shot next time I have to write a test.